# Create database if not exists and then create tables in that database in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL script (in one sql file) which

- Create database if it does not exists
- Create tables if they are not exist

I have started like:

```
IF ServerProperty('Edition') <> 'SQL Azure'
BEGIN
    DECLARE @createDatabaseSqlStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @createDatabaseSqlStatement =
        'DECLARE @TargetDatabase VARCHAR(128) = ''MyDatabase''

        IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE (''['' + name + '']'' = @TargetDatabase OR name = @TargetDatabase)))
        BEGIN

        CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase

        END

        USE [MyDatabase]'

    EXEC sp_executesql @createDatabaseSqlStatement
END

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @DefaultAdministrator   varchar(100) = 'admin'      
DECLARE @DefaultPassword    varchar(100) = 'tester01!!'     
DECLARE @DefaultAdministatorEmail varchar(100) = 'email@address.com'
DECLARE @DefaultUserRoleName    varchar(100) = 'rolename'           
DECLARE @DefaultAdministratorRoleName varchar(100) = 'role'

--CREATE TABLES

--CREATE THE 'AspNetUsers' TABLE
IF OBJECT_ID (N'AspNetUsers', N'U') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers](
        [Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
        [Email] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
        [EmailConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [PasswordHash] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [SecurityStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [PhoneNumberConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [TwoFactorEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [LockoutEndDateUtc] [datetime] NULL,
        [LockoutEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [AccessFailedCount] [int] NOT NULL,
        [UserName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
        [SystemId] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL 
            CONSTRAINT DF__AspNetUsers__SystemId DEFAULT (''),
        [LastLogonTime] [datetime2] NULL,
        [BlockReason] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
        [EmailConfirmationDateUtc] [datetime] NULL
     CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]


    CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UserNameIndex] ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
    (
        [UserName] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
END


...
```

I have issue that tables are not created in `MyDatabase` database and they are stored in `master` database.

How to solve issue ? How to create table into `MyDatabase` database instead of `master` ?

If I put `USE [MyDatabase]` after `SET NOCOUNT ON` then script failed that `MyDatabase` is not found (in SQL Management Studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [GO statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15). It will separate the batches so in one batch you can create your database:

```
IF ServerProperty('Edition') <> 'SQL Azure'
BEGIN
    DECLARE @createDatabaseSqlStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @createDatabaseSqlStatement =
        'DECLARE @TargetDatabase VARCHAR(128) = ''MyDatabase''

        IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE (''['' + name + '']'' = @TargetDatabase OR name = @TargetDatabase)))
        BEGIN

        CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase

        END '

        -- this is not needed here: USE [MyDatabase]'

    EXEC sp_executesql @createDatabaseSqlStatement
END
GO
```

And afterwards you can simply use it by writing:

```
USE [MyDatatabase]
GO
```

And then the rest of your script.

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't look right:

```
    DECLARE @TargetDatabase VARCHAR(128) = ''MyDatabase''

    IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE (''['' + name + '']'' = @TargetDatabase OR name = @TargetDatabase)))
    BEGIN

    CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase

    END

    USE [MyDatabase]
```

This creates a database explicitly called `MyDatabase`, not named based on the value in `@TargetDatabase`.  You would like to do:

```
    CREATE DATABASE @TargetDatabase
```

But that won't work.  So you need dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'CREATE DATABASE @TargetDatabase';

SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '@TargetDatabase', @TargetDatabase);

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Then, the `USE` statement is only valid for that session -- which disappears when the dynamic SQL ends.  My recommendation is simply to include the database name in all the table names:

```
CREATE TABLE MyDatabase.[dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
   . . .
```

Of course, you can use dynamic SQL for this to plug in the variable database name.